flatten-tree flattens lambda body
I'm trying to flatten list. To simplify things, examples below flatten already-flat-list.
(flatten-tree (list :hoge (lambda () 42)))
;; => (:hoge lambda 42)

flatten-tree seems to flatten "body of lambda".
(defun flatten (list)
  (mapcan (lambda (x) (if (listp x) x nil)) list))    
(flatten (list :hoge (lambda () 42))
;; => (:hoge (lambda nil 42))

This is what I expected to flatten-tree.
Why does flatten-tree behave this way?
Is there built-in functions that do this?
I read Name of this function in built-in Emacs Lisp library? and get confused.

Where have you gotten flatten-tree from? It's not an Emacs built-in as far as I can see, and it's hard to explain why it works the way it does if nobody knows what it is.

describe-function says it is from subr.el, added in Emacs 27.1.
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Lists.html#index-flatten_002dtree
